# How to unit testing the filter result of a graphql query in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm working on a website built with Gatsby. To consume the data (coming from an airTable table), I've created a custom hook (useData) that performs a GraphQL query, using useStaticQuery. I need to filter this data according to their status (those that have Status = "open"); so, I've created a filter in the query for it, like this:

```
    useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allAirtable(
        filter: { table: { eq: "Positions" }, data: { Title: { ne: null }, Status: { eq: "open" } } }
      ) {
        nodes {
          data {
            Title
            Location
            Status
            ID
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

The hook useData, looks like this:

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';
import { useTranslateNodes } from './useTranslateNodes';

export default function useData() {
  const queryData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allAirtable(
        filter: { table: { eq: "Positions" }, data: { Title: { ne: null }, Status: { eq: "open" } } }
      ) {
        nodes {
          data {
            Title
            Location
            Status
            ID
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);
  const {
    allAirtable: { nodes },
  } = queryData;

  const positions = useTranslateNodes({ nodes, table: 'Positions' });

  return { positions };
}
```

*(The useTranslateNodes hook, maps the array from the query and returns a better structured array. This is not really important for the issue)*

The problem is when I test the query result (I want to be sure that the hook is doing it's job, and is returning the positions with Status = "open"), because according to the [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/testing-components-with-graphql/), I have to mock the data from the query, but that's not the real data! And it makes no sense to me... I also try using the [gatsby-plugin-testing](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-testing/), to get the real data from the query, but in the end, still taking the mock data (because without it, it doesn't work).

My question is: How can I do a unit test for the filter of the query? I mean, I wanna test that the filter is doing its job!

I hope I have provided the necessary information to resolve this issue. I've been reading related issues here, but still without a concrete solution. I'm a testing newbie and I'm a bit confused about it, so thanks for the help you can provide!